# Jenkins not instrumenting ActiveJDBC model classes

Tags: jenkins, activejdbc

I've created a jenkins job using "Maven 2/3 Project" type.
The java project I'm using uses ActiveJDBC which requires a step in instrumentation while compiling.

From the command line the 'mvn package' works correctly and the classes are instrumented correctly for ActiveJDBC.

When run from Jenkins the model classes are instrumented but not included in instrumented model classes. The application fails with "are you sure models have been instrumented?"

**Why isn't the jenkins job not including the instrumented classes in the war file?**

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I figured it out.

There is a bug with Jenkins that if your Job name contains space characters then the instrumented classes will not be copied to your war file!?

I renamed the job named from "Customer Info App" to "CustomerInfoApp" and it worked perfectly.

**As a general rule, never use white spaces in your job names.**

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your Jenkins configuration. We have been building ActiveJDBC projects on Jenkings for years. It is possible that instrumented classes are compiled again and non-instrumented ones are included instead of instrumented. Look at the Jenkins log and see that instrumentation is called after compilation and not the other way around.

Comment: It turned out that a Job name containing spaces in jenkins makes it fail to include the instrumented classes in the war file. I renamed my job from "Customer Info App" to "CustomerInfoApp" and it worked.

Comment: yeah, I saw some other peoples' comments on forums complaining of spaces in directory names. Job name in Jenkins translates into a directory name, so this makes total sense.